# In-browser JavaScript code editor with syntax highlighting support for Smarty template tags?

Tags: javascript, editor, smarty, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

I have searched high and low on the Interwebs, and found some *really* awesome [JS code editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript-based_source_code_editors) with syntax highlighting and indentation and more... but none seem to have support for [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) template tags yet.

A new Smarty mode for [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net) would be the best, but I'll use a different editor if I need to.

I did find [this blog post](http://antoine.goutenoir.com/blog/2011/10/09/codemirror-2-smarty-syntax-highlighting-mode/)... but it is VERY simple, and I would like to still support mixed HTML/CSS/JS highlighting, like the PHP mode for CodeMirror.

I just thought I would check with the SO hive mind before embarking on rolling my own CodeMirror mode. If I do make a new mode (and get anywhere with it) I'll post it here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help. I wrote a Smarty mode for CodeMirror2 this weekend. See:
http://www.benjaminkeen.com/misc/CodeMirror2/mode/smarty/

I've also forked the CodeMirror project with my change here:
https://github.com/benkeen/CodeMirror2

All the best -

Ben

[EDIT: this is now part of the main script. I'll be shortly adding a Smarty/HTML/CSS/JS mode].

Comment: Sweet, the Smarty mode that's in the core seems to work well. I tried out the mixed smarty mode in your fork though and had some troubles though. I'll keep my eye out for updates. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried out olivier's mixed smarty mode he posted here - seems to work OK if you want to look at it & roll it in to the core.

Answer (score 2):

I made some tries to get a mixed mode with smarty and although my work is not perfect, so far it works well enough for me. I started from de htmlmixedmode to add a smarty mode :

```
  CodeMirror.defineMode("smartymixed", function(config, parserConfig) {
  var htmlMode = CodeMirror.getMode(config, {name: "xml", htmlMode: true});
  var smartyMode = CodeMirror.getMode(config, "smarty");
  var jsMode = CodeMirror.getMode(config, "javascript");
  var cssMode = CodeMirror.getMode(config, "css");



  function html(stream, state) {
    var style = htmlMode.token(stream, state.htmlState);
    if (style == "tag" && stream.current() == ">" && state.htmlState.context) {
      if (/^script$/i.test(state.htmlState.context.tagName)) {
        state.token = javascript;
        state.localState = jsMode.startState(htmlMode.indent(state.htmlState, ""));
        state.mode = "javascript";
      }
      else if (/^style$/i.test(state.htmlState.context.tagName)) {
        state.token = css;
        state.localState = cssMode.startState(htmlMode.indent(state.htmlState, ""));
        state.mode = "css";
      }
    }

    return style;
  }
  function maybeBackup(stream, pat, style) {
    var cur = stream.current();
    var close = cur.search(pat);
    if (close > -1) stream.backUp(cur.length - close);
    return style;
  }
  function javascript(stream, state) {
    if (stream.match(/^<\/\s*script\s*>/i, false)) {
      state.token = html;
      state.localState = null;
      state.mode = "html";
      return html(stream, state);
    }
    return maybeBackup(stream, /<\/\s*script\s*>/,
                       jsMode.token(stream, state.localState));
  }
  function css(stream, state) {
    if (stream.match(/^<\/\s*style\s*>/i, false)) {
      state.token = html;
      state.localState = null;
      state.mode = "html";
      return html(stream, state);
    }
    return maybeBackup(stream, /<\/\s*style\s*>/,
                       cssMode.token(stream, state.localState));
  }

  function smarty(stream, state) {
     style =  smartyMode.token(stream, state.localState);
     if ( state.localState.tokenize == null ) 
          { // back to anything from smarty
          state.token = state.htmlState.tokens.pop();
          state.mode = state.htmlState.modes.pop();
          state.localState = state.htmlState.states.pop(); // state.htmlState;
          }
      return(style);
      }

  return {

    startState: function() {
      var state = htmlMode.startState();
      state.modes = [];
      state.tokens = [];
      state.states = [];
      return {token: html, localState: null, mode: "html", htmlState: state};
    },

    copyState: function(state) { 
      if (state.localState)
        var local = CodeMirror.copyState( 
            ( state.token == css ) ? cssMode : (( state.token == javascript ) ? jsMode : smartyMode ), 
            state.localState);
      return {token: state.token, localState: local, mode: state.mode,
              htmlState: CodeMirror.copyState(htmlMode, state.htmlState)};
    },

    token: function(stream, state) {

      if ( stream.match(/^{[^ ]{1}/,false) )
          { // leaving anything to smarty
          state.htmlState.states.push(state.localState);
          state.htmlState.tokens.push(state.token);
          state.htmlState.modes.push(state.mode);
          state.token = smarty;
              state.localState = smartyMode.startState();
              state.mode = "smarty";
          }

      return state.token(stream, state);
    },


    compareStates: function(a, b) {
      if (a.mode != b.mode) return false;
      if (a.localState) return CodeMirror.Pass;
      return htmlMode.compareStates(a.htmlState, b.htmlState);
    },

    electricChars: "/{}:"
  }
}, "xml", "javascript", "css", "smarty");

CodeMirror.defineMIME("text/html", "smartymixed");
```

The switch to smarty mode is made in token function only but ...
You also have to patch the other basic modes ( css , javascript & xml ) to stop them on the { character so you can fall back in the token function to test it against a regexp ( { followed by a non blank character ).

Comment: Next time, just use a moderator flag.  See the "flag" link below your answer?  Don't use answers for anything but answers.  The only person that gets notified when an answer is posted is the question owner.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the answer : a patch in benjamin smarty file to be able to leave it and fall back in smartymixedmode. So here is the patched verson of mode/smarty/smarty.js

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("smarty", function(config, parserConfig) {
  var breakOnSmarty = ( config.mode == "smartymixed" ) ? true : false; // we are called in a "smartymixed" context
  var keyFuncs = ["debug", "extends", "function", "include", "literal"];
  var last;
  var regs = {
    operatorChars: /[+\-*&%=<>!?]/,
    validIdentifier: /[a-zA-Z0-9\_]/,
    stringChar: /[\'\"]/
  }
  var leftDelim = (typeof config.mode.leftDelimiter != 'undefined') ? config.mode.leftDelimiter : "{";
  var rightDelim = (typeof config.mode.rightDelimiter != 'undefined') ? config.mode.rightDelimiter : "}";
  function ret(style, lst) { last = lst; return style; }


  function tokenizer(stream, state) {
    function chain(parser) {
      state.tokenize = parser;
      return parser(stream, state);
    }

    if (stream.match(leftDelim, true)) {
      if (stream.eat("*")) {
        return chain(inBlock("comment", "*" + rightDelim));
      }
      else {
        state.tokenize = inSmarty;
        return ( breakOnSmarty == true ) ? "bracket" : "tag";
      }
    }
    else {
      // I'd like to do an eatWhile() here, but I can't get it to eat only up to the rightDelim string/char
      stream.next();
      return null;
    }
  }

  function inSmarty(stream, state) {
    if (stream.match(rightDelim, true)) {
      state.tokenize = ( breakOnSmarty ) ? null : tokenizer;
      return ( breakOnSmarty == true ) ? ret("bracket", null) : ret("tag", null);
    }

    var ch = stream.next();
    if (ch == "$") {
      stream.eatWhile(regs.validIdentifier);
      return ret("variable-2", "variable");
    }
    else if (ch == ".") {
      return ret("operator", "property");
    }
    else if (regs.stringChar.test(ch)) {
      state.tokenize = inAttribute(ch);
      return ret("string", "string");
    }
    else if (regs.operatorChars.test(ch)) {
      stream.eatWhile(regs.operatorChars);
      return ret("operator", "operator");
    }
    else if (ch == "[" || ch == "]") {
      return ret("bracket", "bracket");
    }
    else if (/\d/.test(ch)) {
      stream.eatWhile(/\d/);
      return ret("number", "number");
    }
    else {
      if (state.last == "variable") {
        if (ch == "@") {
          stream.eatWhile(regs.validIdentifier);
          return ret("property", "property");
        }
        else if (ch == "|") {
          stream.eatWhile(regs.validIdentifier);
          return ret("qualifier", "modifier");
        }
      }
      else if (state.last == "whitespace") {
        stream.eatWhile(regs.validIdentifier);
        return ret("attribute", "modifier");
      }
      else if (state.last == "property") {
        stream.eatWhile(regs.validIdentifier);
        return ret("property", null);
      }
      else if (/\s/.test(ch)) {
        last = "whitespace";
        return null;
      }

      var str = "";
      if (ch != "/") {
        str += ch;
      }
      var c = "";
      while ((c = stream.eat(regs.validIdentifier))) {
        str += c;
      }
      var i, j;
      for (i=0, j=keyFuncs.length; i<j; i++) {
        if (keyFuncs[i] == str) {
          return ret("keyword", "keyword");
        }
      }
      if (/\s/.test(ch)) {
        return null;
      }
      return ret("tag", "tag");
    }
  }

  function inAttribute(quote) {
    return function(stream, state) {
      while (!stream.eol()) {
        if (stream.next() == quote) {
          state.tokenize = inSmarty;
          break;
        }
      }
      return "string";
    };
  }

  function inBlock(style, terminator) {
    return function(stream, state) {
      while (!stream.eol()) {
        if (stream.match(terminator)) {
          state.tokenize = ( breakOnSmarty == true ) ? null : tokenizer;
          break;
        }
        stream.next();
      }
      return style;
    };
  }

  return {
    startState: function() {
      return { tokenize: tokenizer, mode: "smarty", last: null };
    },
    token: function(stream, state) {
      var style = state.tokenize(stream, state);
      state.last = last;
      return style;
    },
    electricChars: ""
  }
});

CodeMirror.defineMIME("text/x-smarty", "smarty");
```

The 1st line check if we are called by the smartymixed mode and tests are made on this contition, allowing smarty mode to run as before.